# A[j] = 2∗A[i] in list with better than O(n^2) runtime

Tags: java, python, arrays, algorithm, big-o

below I've listed a problem I'm having some trouble with. This problem is a simple nested loop away from an O(n^2) solution, but I need it to be O(n). Any ideas how this should be tackled? Would it be possible to form two equations?

Given an integer array A, check if there are two indices i and j such that A[j] = 2∗A[i]. For example, on the array (25, 13, 16, 7, 8) the algorithm should output “true” (since 16 = 2 * 8), whereas on the array (25, 17, 44, 24) the algorithm should output “false”. Describe an algorithm for this problem with worst-case running time that is better than O(n^2), where n is the length of A.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great spot to use a hash table. Create a hash table and enter each number in the array into the hash table. Then, iterate across the array one more time and check whether 2*A[i] exists in the hash table for each i. If so, then you know a pair of indices exists with this property. If not, you know no such pair exists.

On expectation, this takes time O(n), since n operations on a hash table take expected amortized O(1) time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why use a hash table instead of a set?  Just because you can?

Comment: This is a practice question for an exam. Would this be the fastest way (in terms of writing)? Would a set work as well? I've never implemented a hash table before.

Comment: @MattFenwick Python sets are implemented in terms of hash tables.

Comment: Would you intersect two sets, one with the list numbers and one with the list numbers doubled?

Comment: @lvc sorry, but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: What is the runtime of intersecting two sets?

Comment: @MattFenwick using a set (at least, using Python's builtin `set`) *is* 'using a hash table' - the answer doesn't say 'use a `dict`'.

Comment: Both `dict`s and `set`s are implemented on top of hash tables.  In many languages, dicts are called "hashmaps" and their keys are "keysets", so you can see the overlap.

Comment: So basically, if I'm understanding this correctly, a set in Python is equivalent to a Hashtable in Java?

Comment: @Turtle-in-a-bash-shell I would expect set intersection to be O(n). There is *probably* no time advantage of building two sets and intersecting them as compared to a linear search with one set. A Python dict is similar to a Java HashMap; a set is similar to a HashSet.

Comment: According to the Python time complexity chart the intersection operation is O(len(s) * len(t)) or O(n^2) in this case unfortunately.

Comment: @lvc sorry, but you're still not getting my question.  Using a set is not 'using a hash table', it's using a set.  The question is why use a hash table instead of a set?

Comment: @MattFenwick- When I wrote this answer, I noticed the question was tagged with both [java] and [python]. I don't have much experience with Python and figured that I would give my answer in terms of the appropriate underlying data structure rather than concrete types like sets so that I could (1) guarantee the time complexity across language barriers and (2) ensure that I wasn't accidentally making a Python mistake. Since it looks like sets in Python are backed by hash tables, it seems appropriate to use sets in this case.

Answer (score 0):

templatetypedef's suggestion to use a hash table is a good one. I want to explain a little more about *why*.

The key here is realizing that you are essentially searching for some value in a set. You have a set of numbers you are searching *in* (2 * each value in the input array), and a set of numbers you are searching *for* (each value in the input array). Your brute-force naive case is just looking up values directly in the search-in array. What you *want* to do is pre-load your "search-in" set into something with faster lookups than an array (like a hash table), then you can search from there.

You can also further prune your results by not searching for `A[i]` where `A[i]` is odd; because you know that `A[i] = 2 * A[j]` can never be true if `A[i]` is odd. You can also compute the minimum and maximum values in the "search-in" array on the fly during initialization and prune all `A[i]` outside that range.

The performance there is hard to express in big O form since it depends on the nature of the data, but you can calculate a best- and worst- case and an amortized case as well.

However, a proper choice of hash table size (if your value range is small you can simply choose a capacity that is larger than your value range, where the hash function is the value itself) may actually make pruning more costly than not in some cases, you'd have to profile it to find out.